# Блокировка дат в календаре vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, как заблокировать прошедшие даты в календаре во vue + сегодняшний день.

```
<CustomInput type="date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CustomInput type="date" :min="minDate" :max="maxDate" v-model="selectedDate" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedDate: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    minDate() {
      // Получаем текущую дату и преобразуем в формат YYYY-MM-DD,
      // чтобы использовать в атрибуте 'min'
      const today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
      return today;
    },
    maxDate() {
      // Оставим максимальную дату неограниченной (по желанию)
      return null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

В этом примере minDate вычисляется как текущая дата, и она будет ограничивать выбор дат, предотвращая выбор прошедших дат и сегодняшнего дня. Атрибут maxDate не установлен, чтобы не ограничивать верхнюю дату, но вы можете задать его, если хотите ограничить максимально допустимую дату.

Помимо этого, вы можете стилизовать ваш компонент CustomInput по вашим потребностям и учесть визуальное представление заблокированных дат.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает! Но как заблокировать  + сегодняшний день ? Чтоб календарь начинался с завтра. Сейчас вижу что заблокирован вчерашний день, но сегодняшний активный.

Comment: minDate добавь 24  часа